# ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER Decrypting Saved Chrome Passwords C++

Tags: c++, sqlite, winapi, c++17

I'm working on a program that decrypts my Chrome saved passwords, but instead of successfully decrypting them, I get an error code 87. I've looked that up and according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-, it means there's an invalid parameter (ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER). I've tried everything I can think of to fix the problem, but I can't figure out what is invalid.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "crypt32")
const char* uncryptData(BYTE* password, int size)
{
    DATA_BLOB in;
    DATA_BLOB out;

    in.pbData = password;
    in.cbData = (size + 1);
    if (CryptUnprotectData(&in, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, &out))
    {
        out.pbData[out.cbData] = 0;
        return ((const char*)out.pbData);
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "error: " << GetLastError() << "\n";
    }
    return ("Error");
}

void printPassword(sqlite3_stmt* stmt)
{
    std::string infos;
    std::string url = (const char*)sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0);
    std::string login = (const char*)sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1);
    

    if (login != "")
    {
        std::string password = uncryptData((BYTE*)sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 3), sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 2));
        infos = (url + ':' + login + ':' + password);
        std::cout << (infos)+"\n";
    }
}

void findPasswordTable(sqlite3* db)
{
    int i = 0;
    sqlite3_stmt* stmt;

    std::cout << ("Database open\n");
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "SELECT origin_url, username_value, length(password_value), password_value FROM logins", -1, &stmt, 0) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        while (sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            printPassword(stmt);
            i++;
        }
    }
    else
        std::cout << ("Error compiling query\n");
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    sqlite3_close(db);
}





int main() {
    sqlite3* db;
    std::string dbPath = "C:/Users/*user*/Desktop/New folder/Login Data";
    if (sqlite3_open(dbPath.c_str(), &db) == SQLITE_OK)
        findPasswordTable(db);
    else
        std::cout << ("Error opening database");
}
```

Comment: The Third Parameter:[*however, if an optional entropy DATA_BLOB structure was used in the encryption phase, that same DATA_BLOB structure must be used for the decryption phase. For information about protecting passwords, see Handling Passwords.*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dpapi/nf-dpapi-cryptunprotectdata#parameters)

Comment: According to Chrome's source code that parameter is NULL when the data is encrypted.